# Cannot understand disk architecture on Synology NAS RS3412RPxs : is /dev/sdkb3 a physical or logical disk?

Tags: software-raid, synology-diskstation

I have the following synology `RS3412RPxs` NAS :

```shell
$ uname -u
synology_bromolow_rs3412rpxs
$
```

with the following MD-RAID array rebuilding `/dev/sdkb3` on the `RX1211rp-1` extension unit :

```shell
$ sudo mdadm -D /dev/md4 | egrep -i "rebuild|raid"
     Raid Level : raid6
   Raid Devices : 12
 Rebuild Status : 6% complete
    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
      18      65      499        1      spare rebuilding   /dev/sdkb3
$
```

When I take a look at `/dev/sdkb3`, it seems like a physical disk :

```shell
$ sudo smartctl -i /dev/sdkb3
smartctl 6.5 (build date Mar  2 2021) [x86_64-linux-3.10.105] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-16, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Model Family:     Seagate Constellation CS
Device Model:     ST3000NC002-1DY166
Serial Number:    Z1F4MEC0
LU WWN Device Id: 5 000c50 065f59db7
Firmware Version: CN02
User Capacity:    3,000,592,982,016 bytes [3.00 TB]
Sector Sizes:     512 bytes logical, 4096 bytes physical
Rotation Rate:    7200 rpm
Form Factor:      3.5 inches
Device is:        In smartctl database [for details use: -P show]
ATA Version is:   ATA8-ACS T13/1699-D revision 4
SATA Version is:  SATA 3.0, 6.0 Gb/s (current: 3.0 Gb/s)
Local Time is:    Fri Jun 23 18:16:18 2023 CEST
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled

$
```

but `parted` does not recognise its model nor its "disk lablel" :

```shell
$ sudo parted /dev/sdkb3 print
Error: /dev/sdkb3: unrecognised disk label
Model: Unknown (unknown)
Disk /dev/sdkb3: 2996GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: unknown
Disk Flags:
$ lsblk
-sh: lsblk: command not found
$
```

Is `/dev/sdkb3` a physical disk or a logical disk ?

EDIT0 : /dev/sdkb3 is pointing to :

```shell
$ readlink -f /sys/class/block/sdkb3
/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.1/0000:02:00.0/0000:03:05.0/0000:07:00.0/ata12/host11/target11:1:0/11:1:0:0/block/sdkb/sdkb3
$
```

It seems `/dev/sdkb3` was a partition and `sfdisk` confirms it :

```shell
$ sudo sfdisk -l /dev/sdkb3
[/dev/sdkb3] is a partition

$
```

EDIT1 : `smartctl` outputs the same result for `/dev/sdkb3` than for `/dev/sdkb` which induced me into error.

Therefore, I believe `/dev/sdkb` is a physical disk :

```shell
$ sudo parted /dev/sdkb print
Model: ATA ST3000NC002-1DY1 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdkb: 3001GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags:

Number  Start   End     Size    File system  Name  Flags
 1      1049kB  2551MB  2550MB                     raid
 2      2551MB  4699MB  2147MB                     raid
 3      4832MB  3001GB  2996GB                     raid

$
```

Sorry guys for the inconvenience.

Comment: What does `readlink -f /sys/class/block/sdkb3` point to?

Comment: @user1686 Please see my EDIT0.

Comment: @user1686 I get it, smartctl outputs the same result for `/dev/sdkb3` than for `/dev/sdkb`, I thought `/dev/sdkb3` was a disk but it was in fact a partition of `/dev/sdkb`

Comment: @user1686 Thanks a lot.